# unordered_map can't find the key

Tags: c++, c++11

i used unorder_map in my program. the problem is it can't find the key which i have inserted in the map sometimes, i don't know the reason, the following is my code:

```
class FlowKey: public std::pair<const char*, unsigned int>
{
public:
    FlowKey(const char* s, unsigned int l): std::pair<const char*, unsigned int>(s, l) {
            fprintf(stderr, "raw string %s len %u, after pair, first %s second %u", s, l, this-     >first, this->second);
    }
    bool operator==(const FlowKey& c) const
    {
            if (this->second == c.second) {
                    if (0 == strncmp((char*)this->first, (char*)c.first, this->second)) {
                            fprintf(stderr, "key compare true\n");
                            return true;
                    } else {
                            fprintf(stderr, "this first ip:%s c first ip:%s\n", (char*)this->first, (char*)c.first);
                    }
            } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "this second %d, c second %d\n", this->second, c.second);
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "key compare false\n");
            return false;
    }
};

class FlowKeyHash
{
 public:
    size_t operator()(const FlowKey& that ) const
    {
            unsigned int h = fnv_32a_buf(that.first, that.second, FNV_32A_INIT);
            fprintf(stderr, "ip %s len %u digest %u\n", that.first, that.second, h);
            return (size_t) h;
    }
};
typedef std::unordered_map<unsigned int, TcpInfo*, EmptyHash> UserAgent_Map;
typedef std::unordered_map<FlowKey, UserAgent_Map, FlowKeyHash> IP_Map;
```

usage:

```
FlowKey k(ipString, strlen(ipString));
IP_Map::iterator it = m_iptable.find(k);
if (it == m_iptable.end()) {
            //insert new entry to ip table and useragent table
            struct timeval time;
            gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "ip not equel, insert: ip:(%s)ip-digest(%u), k first:%s k second %d tablesize %d hashsize %lu\n", ipString, ip_digest, k.first, k.second, m_tableSize, m_iptable.size());
            for(it = m_iptable.begin(); it != m_iptable.end(); ++it) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "key %s len %d\n", it->first.first, it->first.second);
            }
            ++m_tableSize;
    } else {
            //update ip table
            struct timeval time;
            gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
            UserAgent_Map::iterator it2 = it->second.find(user_agent_digest);
            if (it2 == it->second.end()) {
                    //insert new entry to user_agent table
                    ++m_tableSize;
                    fprintf(stderr, "user-agent not equel, insert: use-agent-digest(%u)\n", user_agent_digest);
            }
```

the program has inserted a key pair(192.168.2.20, 12), it can be found this key sometime, but occasionally can't find this key, the log display:

```
raw key 192.168.2.20 len 12, after pair, first 192.168.2.20 second 12
ip 192.168.2.20 len 12 digest 1737338608
this first ip:192.168.2.20 c first ip:184.28.16.107
key compare false
ip 192.168.2.20 len 12 digest 1737338608
this first ip:192.168.2.20 c first ip:184.28.16.107
key compare false
ip not equel, insert: ip:(192.168.2.20)ip-digest(1737338608), k first:192.168.2.20 k second 12 tablesize 1 hashsize 2
key 192.168.2.20 len 12
key 184.28.16.107 len 12
```

it's so strange, the key which to be searched is <192.168.2.20, 12>, and it has been in the map, why the find function can't find it, why the searched key changed to 184.28.16.107 during the find() call. before and after find(), the key is 192.168.2.20, during the find, it's 184.28.16.107, and the len is 12 not right, why, and where is the key<184.28.16.107,12> from, anybody can find my usage of unordered_map is wrong? or the program's logical error, i cost a lot of time for this, but i can't find any reason. can you help me?

Comment: So... what happened to the original `char *` pointer that addresses the initial insertion? Or is its lifetime not something you considered important (note: it *is* important). You're looking for something you expect to find, hence you must have added it prior (and conveniently omitted that code from your post, squelching any hopes of reproducibility on our end). What happened to that pointer (and the content it points to) between *that* insertion and *this* lookup?

Comment: WhozCraig, i added some log in my program, see my new edit ,the key <192.168.2.20, 12> indeed has been inserted into the map. but during the find(), the searched key changed from 192.168.2.20 to 184.28.16.107, i don't know why

Comment: its because the pointer you're adding is to a buffer that is being reused, or worse, it in scope that is later left resulting in a dangling pointer. I *strongly* suggest you use a `std::pair<std::string,unsigned int>` and change your hash function to use `that.first.c_str()` for the first param of the hash calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a lot like a dangling pointer problem like WhozCraig analysed. You're may be using the same `ipString` twice or thrice...

Can you change the "const char*" in your pair for a string ? I bet it'll solve your problem.

Comment: yes, you are right, char* just a value copy, don't have copy the whole char string, change to string is all right, thank you very much.